# Trying to install v-select getting Vue is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, v-select

New to Vue, but trying to get v-select working. I'm getting `vue is not defined` when importing. Then when I import `vue` I'm getting a different error as listed below:

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import vSelect from 'vue-select'
Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';


createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**Error**

```
-- 'Vue' is not defined
```

When adding `import Vue from 'vue'`

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've installed the right version of `v-select` that's compatible with vue 3 you should use `app.component(...)` to register it not `Vue.component(...)` :

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import vSelect from 'vue-select'
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

const app=createApp(App)
app.component('v-select', vSelect)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: I installed `npm install vue-select@beta`